# Running a python script several times at the same time?

Tags: python, python-2.7, cmd

I have got a python (2.7) script and I would like to start it in multiple CMDs at the same time. Is this possible or would the script crash?

Answer (score 0):

It's totally posible and will fork fine.

Comment: It's possible, but "forking" has nothing to do with it when you start it from the CMD prompt.